# How do I print the line where the max value is found using awk?

Tags: awk, max

I have a file called probabilities.txt and it's a two column file with the first column listing distances and the second column probabilities.

The sample data is as follows:

```
0.2      0.05
0.4      0.10
0.6      0.63
0.8      0.11
1.0      0.03 
...      ...
10.0     0.01
```

I would like to print out the line that has the maximum value in column 2. I've tried the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a= 0} {if ($2 > a) a = $2} END{print $1, a}' probabilities.txt
```

This was the desired output:

```
0.6     0.63
```

But this is the output I get:

```
10.0      0.63
```

It seems like the code I wrote is just getting the max value in each column and then printing it out rather than printing out the line that has the max value in column 2. Printing out $0 also just prints out the last line of the file.

I assume one could fix this by treating the lines as an array rather than a scalar but I'm not really sure how to do that since I'm a beginner. Would appreciate any help

Comment: Would `awk 'BEGIN{a=0; b=0} {if ($2 > a) {a=$2; b=$1}} END {print b, a}' probabilities.txt` solve your problem? Seems like an easy fix, but there are a number of ways you could approach this task

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't change the output, it's still the incorrect (10.0, 0.63). Yeah I looked around for a while before asking since it seemed like a simple problem, but nothing has worked so far, so I'm really stumped

Comment: The code in comments does work if you use your sample data though...

Comment: Sorry @ChemistryCoding, I may have misunderstood. Using your example dataset and copying/pasting the code from my comment gives the correct answer on my system (and, presumably Andre Wildberg's system). Are you saying that 'it doesn't work' when applied to the example dataset on your system? Or are you saying it doesn't work on your actual data?

Comment: It should work but it doesn't, and I'm not sure why it doesn't. It doesn't work on my actual data or on this sample data.

Comment: If possible, it would be great if you could edit your question to include some more details such as your shell (e.g. bash) your version of awk (e.g. output from `awk --version`) and copy the exact command from your terminal and the exact output (just to see if there are any typos). Something weird might be going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had contemplated just leaving the answer as a comment, but given the trouble you had with the command it's worth writing up. To begin, you don't need `BEGIN`. In `awk` variables are initialized `0` until set, so you can simply use a `max` variable for the first time after comparing it.

**Note:** If your data involves negative numbers (neither distance or probabilities can), just add a new first rule and set `max` to the value in the first record (e.g. `FNR==1 (max=$2; next}`)

Next, you don't save individual field values when you are wanting to capture the entire line (record) with the largest probability, save the entire record associated with the `max` value. Then in your `END` rule all you need to do is print that record.

Putting it altogether you would have:

```bash
awk '{if($2 > max) {max=$2; maxline=$0}} END {print maxline}' file
```

or, if you prefer:

```bash
awk '$2 > max {max=$2; maxline=$0} END {print maxline}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `distprobs.txt` you would get:

```
$ awk '{if($2 > max) {max=$2; maxline=$0}} END {print maxline}' distprobs.txt
0.6      0.63
```

and, second version same result:

```
$ awk '$2 > max {max=$2; maxline=$0} END {print maxline}' distprobs.txt
0.6      0.63
```